# Reduce with obj key, value not working as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, reduce

I'm trying to dynamically create a sqlite insert string with node. I have:

```
function update_json_obj_into_table(tablename, obj, search_condition) {

  const insertValues = Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [k,v]) => acc.push(`${k} = ${v}`), []);

  const insertValuesString = Array.prototype.join.call(insertValues, '/');

 console.log(insertValuesString);
 console.log(`UPDATE ${tablename} SET ${insertValues} WHERE ${search_condition}`);
 // db.run(`UPDATE ${tablename} SET ${insertValuesString} WHERE search_condition ;`);
};
```

When I run it :

```
 const obj = {Code: 'A1'};
 update_json_obj_into_table('mytable', obj, 'search_condition')
```

I get:

```
 UPDATE mytable SET 1 WHERE search_condition.
```

Obviously the insertValues is not working correctly. I was expecting:

Code = 1

but its coming out as '1' . What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.push` returns the new length of the array, not the mutated array. While you could put the `.push` on its own line and return the array on the next line:

```js
function update_json_obj_into_table(tablename, obj, search_condition) {

  const insertValues = Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [k, v]) => {
    acc.push(`${k} = ${v}`);
    return acc;
  }, []);

  const insertValuesString = Array.prototype.join.call(insertValues, '/');

  console.log(insertValuesString);
  console.log(`UPDATE ${tablename} SET ${insertValues} WHERE ${search_condition}`);
  // db.run(`UPDATE ${tablename} SET ${insertValuesString} WHERE search_condition ;`);
};


const obj = {
  Code: 'A1'
};
update_json_obj_into_table('mytable', obj, 'search_condition')
```

It would make a lot more sense to use `.map`, since the input array and ouput `insertValues` array are one-to-one:

```js
function update_json_obj_into_table(tablename, obj, search_condition) {

  const insertValues = Object.entries(obj)
    .map(([k, v]) => `${k} = ${v}`);

  const insertValuesString = Array.prototype.join.call(insertValues, '/');

  console.log(insertValuesString);
  console.log(`UPDATE ${tablename} SET ${insertValues} WHERE ${search_condition}`);
  // db.run(`UPDATE ${tablename} SET ${insertValuesString} WHERE search_condition ;`);
};


const obj = {
  Code: 'A1'
};
update_json_obj_into_table('mytable', obj, 'search_condition')
```

That said, dynamically constructed queries like these are rarely a good idea - unless the input is trustworthy, it can compromise your database. Even if the input is trustworthy, it can be inelegant due to delimiter escaping issues, reserved works, and so on. Better to look up how to use prepared statements instead, so that the *database driver* handles the interpolation of external values.